# Python Regex with duplicate field names but different values

Tags: python, regex

I have the string below and I am interested in extracting the bolded text.  *Just a note that the ID that I need must be connected the name Erik:

```
"startRow":0,"endRow":1,"totalRows":2,"rowsReturned":2,"test":[{"id":1,"date":"2015-01-28 12:06:24","name":"first"},{**"id":8**,"date":"2015-01-29 07:39:21","name":"Erik"}
```

I am using the regex `("id":)(\d+)(,"date":)(.*)(,"name":"Erik")` but this returns to me id:1

Is there any way to just get the id associated with the name erik?

Comment: Are you working with JSON data?  If so, why not parse it using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) and then access the item you want by index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negated character class `[^,]*` instead of `.*` because `.*` is greedy by default and it matches all the characters as much as possible. Non-greedy regex `.*?` also won't work here because `.` matches also the character comma. This `[^,]*` matches any character but not of comma , zero or more times.

```
("id":)(\d+)(,"date":)([^,]*)(,"name":"Erik")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/12)

Remove the extra capturing groups to return only the id.

```
>>> s = '"startRow":0,"endRow":1,"totalRows":2,"rowsReturned":2,"test":[{"id":1,"date":"2015-01-28 12:06:24","name":"first"},{"id":8,"date":"2015-01-29 07:39:21","name":"Erik"}'
>>> re.findall(r'"id":(\d+),"date":[^,]*,"name":"Erik"', s)
['8']
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way to do this is deserialize the JSON structure, and extract the relevant information. E.g.,

```
import json

data = '''{"startRow":0,"endRow":1,"totalRows":2,"rowsReturned":2,"test":[{"id":1,"date":"2015-01-28 12:06:24","name":"first"},{"id":8,"date":"2015-01-29 07:39:21","name":"Erik"}]}'''
data = json.loads(data)

for row in data['test']:
    print("ID: {}".format(row['id']))
    print("Date: {}".format(row['date']))
    print("Name: {}".format(row['name']))
```